# Trying to use javascript variable in an append statement for an a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an append statement and I am trying to pass a javascript variable for the ahref attribute.But it is getting rendered as text.I want to know how do i pass the variable as a variable and not text in this append statement

```
jQuery('#sidr-main').append('<a class="navlink level0 addedMenu" href="abc"><li class="navlist level0">some link</li></a>');
```

abc is a js variable which i declared at another place  and i want the value to be passed in the DOM as a variable and not the text there is no link called abc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('#sidr-main').append('<a class="navlink level0 addedMenu" href="' + encodeURIComponent(abc) + '"><li class="navlist level0">some link</li></a>');
```

Make sure you do [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) :)

In ES6 you could also use [templated literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get something more cleaner:

```
var str = `<a class="navlink level0 addedMenu" href="${encodeURIComponent(abc)}"><li class="navlist level0">some link</li></a>`
jQuery('#sidr-main').append(str)
```

Comment: Great! If this is what you needed you should mark the answer so others can find it easier etc.

Comment: i upvoted it but i dont have enough reputations for it to show up :(

Comment: np - no worries at all :)